# Add anchor to pdf using itext java and html

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext, anchor

I try generate pdf from html using IText java. I need create link anchor. The sample code below.

Java code:

```
String k = pdfService.all(request);
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(k.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
document.close();
```

Html code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       <title>title</title>
     </head>
     <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
      <p><a href="#anccc" >GoTo</a></p>
      ... some code ...
      <p id="anccc">anchor</p>
     </body>
  </html>
```

But in the end when you click on the link does not go to anchor

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, internal anchors are created like this:

```
<a href="#myanchor">Click here to go to my anchor</a>
...
<a name="myanchor">This is the destination of a link</a>
```

That's supported in XML Worker.

Adding an `id` attribute to a `<p>` tag is not supported.